# Не работает код для нахождения количества 7-и значных чисел произведение цифр которых делиться на 15

Tags: python, алгоритм, математика

```
otv=0
for n in range(1000000,9999999):
    mult=1
    while n>0:
        if n%10!=0:
            mult=mult*(n%10)
            n=n//10
            print(mult)
    if mult%15==0:
        otv=otv+1
        print(otv)
print(otv)
```

Comment: А что делать с нулевыми цифрами по условию?

Comment: а какое условие использовать?

Comment: Это вы скажите - считать ли 7770777 как число, произведение цифр которого делится на 15, или не делится? Какое у вас условие?

Comment: Вы так и не ответили: 0 делится на 15 или нет?

Comment: Я тоже не знаю надо ли считать числа с нулем>

Answer (score 4):

Решение, которое работает почти мгновенно)

```
res = [ [5,3,1,0], [0,0,0,0] ]
u = 0
for n in range(1,7):
    res[1-u][0] = res[u][0] * 5 
    res[1-u][1] = res[u][1] * 8 + res[u][0] * 3 
    res[1-u][2] = res[u][2] * 6 + res[u][0] 
    res[1-u][3] = res[u][3] * 10 + res[u][0] + res[u][1] * 2 + res[u][2] * 4
    u = 1 - u

print(res[u][3])
```

Ответ 6701037 . Если не надо учитывать 0 то

```
res[1-u][0] = res[u][0] * 6 
res[1-u][1] = res[u][1] * 9 + res[u][0] * 3
res[1-u][2] = res[u][2] * 7 + res[u][0] 
res[1-u][3] = res[u][3] * 10 + res[u][1]  + res[u][2] * 3
```

Работает так же быстро.

Идея - не перебирать сами числа, а набирать его по цифрам пробрасывая флаг.

Теперь откуда взялись "магические" константы. 
Первая цифра числа - что-то от 1 до 9. Из них 5 цифр ни на что не делятся (1,2,4,7,8), 3 цифры делятся на 3 (3,6,9) и 1 на 5 (5). Вот и база пересчёта.

Дальше. Пусть у нас есть способ получить число, у которого произведение цифр ни на что не делится. Тогда мы можем дописать цифру 5 способами что бы оно по прежнему не делилось.  3 способа сделать чтобы делилось на 3, 1 способ на 5 и 1 способ на 15 (дописав 0). аналогично все остальные.

Если делится на 3, то 8 способов не изменить и 2 способа сделать чтобы делилось на 15 (5 и 0). Если делится на 5, то 6 способов не изменить и 4 - чтобы делилось на 15 (0,3,6,9). Ну и если делится на 15 - то уже ничего не сделаешь.

Comment: Красиво (свой ответ убираю, как недостойный быть рядом :)), но все же, можно чуть подробнее?

Comment: @Harry так понятно?)

Comment: Идея - да, над конкретностями нужно подумать...

Answer (score 2):

Это отдельный ответ. Дополнительный к https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1077332/182935

```
print(10**7 - 10**6 - 6**7 - 8**7 + 5**7)
```

Теперь что тут за магия) (сравнивайте с другим ответом).

Очевидно, что `res[u][0] + res[u][1] + res[u][2] + res[u][3] = 10**7 - 10**6`, что логично. любое число попадёт в одну из групп.

Дальше очевидно что `res[u][0] = 5**7` (чтобы произведение ни на что не делилось нужно и достаточно, что бы число состояло только из цифр `{1,2,4,7,8}`).

Теперь `res[u][1] + res[u][0]` - числа у которых произведение не делится на 5. Их число очевидно равно `8**7` (любые цифры, кроме 0 и 5). 
Аналогично `res[u][2] + res[u][0] == 6**7`.

Отсюда `res[u][3] = 10**7 - 10**6 - (res[u][0] + res[u][1] + res[u][2]) = 10**7 - 10**6 - (res[u][1] + res[u][0]) - (res[u][2] + res[u][0]) + res[u][0]` (добавили и вычли `res[u][0]`)

Дальше подставляя `res[u][3] = 10**7 - 10**6 - 6**7 - 8**7 + 5**7`

P.S. раз уж тег математика поставили)

Answer (score 0):

```
count=0
for n in range(1000000,9999999+1):
    mult=1
    mult_list = list(map(int, list(str(n))))
    for m in mult_list:
        mult*=m
    if mult%15==0:
        count+=1
        print(count)
print(f'Count of %15 ={count}')
```

Comment: 0 делится на 15?

Comment: @Эникейщик 0 делится на все, кроме 0.

Answer (score 0):

Ошибки:

1. У вас не входит последнее число
2. Вы внутри цикла изменяете счетчик цикла
3. Неверно идет вычисление произведения цифр: вычисляем целую часть только когла цифра не нулевая, а нужно всегда

Вот ваш исправленный код

```
otv=0
for n in range(1000000,10000000):
    mult=1
    m=n
    while m>0:
        if m%10!=0:
            mult=mult*(m%10)
        m=m//10
    if mult%15==0:
        otv=otv+1
print(otv)
```